# What does the duplicates cost is Team City mean?

Tags: teamcity

We are using Team City, and running a duplicates test.

It has found several duplicates, but I am wondering how the cost is calculated and if we should use that to prioritise fixing the duplicates?

Here are some examples:

cost 246, 2 duplicates in 1 file
cost 75, 14 duplicates in 14 files
cost 73, 2 duplicates in 1 file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number is a synthetic one reflecting "complexity" of the code snippet involved. The more the number, the more complex/long the code is.

It usually makes sense to fight with the duplicates with greater cost first.